# Tex Live 2015 Fundamental package texlive.infra not present

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I updated to `Tex Live 2015` on `Ubuntu 14.04`. When I try to update the packages using the following command

```
tlmgr update --self --all
```

I get the following error:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.uib.no/systems/texlive/tlnet

Fundamental package texlive.infra not present, uh oh, goodbyeShould not happen, texlive.infra not found at /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr line 6110.
```

Any idea to figure out this problem. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

`tlmgr show texlive.infra` says

```
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.uib.no/systems/texlive/tlnet
package:     texlive.infra
category:    TLCore
shortdesc:   basic TeX Live infrastructure
longdesc:    This package contains the files needed to get the TeX Live tools (notably tlmgr) running: perl modules, xz binaries, plus (sometimes) tar and wget.  These files end up in the standalone install packages, and in the tlcritical repository.
installed:   No
sizes:       doc: 185k, run: 1057k, bin: 349k
relocatable: No
collection:  collection-basic
```

Do I need to reinstall `Tex Live 2015`? Or there is any workaround for this problem.

Comment: perhaps a faulty repo. Try manually specifying another repo, http://www.ctan.org/mirrors

Comment: @daleif: Please can you explain in more detail.

Comment: Do I need to reinstall `Tex Live 2015`? Or there is any workaround for this problem.

Comment: No, just ask tlmgr to use a different repository to get its data from. That is what `tlmgr` is complaining about above. `texlive.infra` does no seem to be present on the repository that you are currently using, and it HAS to. So something is wrong with that mirror. Just choose a different one. I had to switch to one in the Netherlands because the Danish mirror was unreliable.

Comment: BTW: `texlive.intra` *is* present in that repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a chat session, we seem to have a grip with what is going on. The `intra` file seems corrupt. This can happen sometimes. Best method to fix is is to go to http://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet and download  (this is for Linux and Mac, there is also an `.exe` file for Windows) and then run it.

```
sh up­date-tlmgr-lat­est.sh
```

then everything should be working again.

(this is most likely a duplicate of another answer)

Comment: Tried different mirror but getting the same error.

Comment: Yes I tried it as root. TL15 is working fine but I'm afraid that it is not installed properly. Might be internet broken during installing, that is I want to update packages.

Comment: On root `sudo which tlmgr` doesn't show anything but `which tlmgr` says `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/i386-linux//tlmgr`.

Comment: For Ubuntu the command worked with `kdesudo sh -c 'PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux sh update-tlmgr-r44836.sh'`